# Usage of simple past in stories

Tags: tense

I have often heard that when explaining stories we must use simple past and not past perfect. Yet when I was reading [this story](https://www.thegermanproject.com/stories/chicken-little) of Henry Hünchen by fable cottage, I observe they use present as well to describe past in the story.

So, is the rule that stories are written in "simple past" not general?

Comment: Can you point out some examples of past perfect in that story? I don't see any at all. (Nor simple past actually, just present.)

Comment: @DonHolgo "Ich habe es im Internet gesehen" looks suspiciously like perfect to me. And it's a somewhat key sentence in the story.

Comment: @tofro Yes, but that's direct speech in the story, not how the story itself is told. Anyway, the question originally asked about simple past vs. past perfect, and that sentence still is neither.

Answer (score 7):

First off, a suggestion: English tempora and German tempora are not the same and they are used quite differently (albeit there being similarities). I suggest you use German denominations for German and English denominations for English. i.e. in German there is a *Präteritum* (sometimes also called *Imperfekt*), but no "simple past".

To be honest, I haven't read the whole story, but as far as I read it was in *Präsens*. Here are some quotes:

> Er **ist** weder groß noch klein. [...] Er **liest** die Nachrichten im Internet. Dort **sieht** er [...]

In German there is a certain *consecutio temporum*, an order of tempora at work. If your main sentence is in *Präsens*, then you use *Perfekt* to describe what happened before (of what happens in the main sentence). If your main sentence is in *Präteritum* then you use *Plusquamperfekt* instead. This is similar to English, where you use present perfect to describe what happened before a main sentence in present time and past perfect to describe what happened before a main sentence in (simple) past.

> Ich **gehe**, nachdem ich **ausgetrunken habe**.
> Ich **ging**, nachdem ich **ausgetrunken hatte**.

> I **go**, after I **have finished** drinking.
> I **went**, after I **had finished** drinking.

So, because the whole story is in *Präsens,* anteriority is expressed by *Perfekt*.

This begs the question why the story is told in *Präsens* at all. After all, storytelling is done in *Präteritum* usually. This is a story addressed to (little) children. The *Präsens* makes the story appear to happen *right now* and this stylistic tool is intended to draw the recipient into it more strongly. It tries to make the child an immediate participant - as the story unfolds it is put into the position of a bystander watching what happens.

Style in general is the application (and sometimes breach) of the rules which generally apply. Art - this is true for storytelling as well as drawing, music, or any other form of artistic fabrication - basically walks a fine line between fulfilling and frustrating the expectations of the recipient. Fulfill expectations too often and the piece becomes boring and predictable. Disappoint too often and the piece becomes angular and chaotic. But in between there is a golden equilibrium of *interesting*. All great artists have learned and applied all the rules there were - and then broken them. But - and this is important - broken them only at *just the right moment*.

Comment: "this stylistic tool is intended to stronger draw the recipient into it" - I'm not convinced we have to go to such depths of analysis. Yes, this *is* a story addressed to (little) children, and for that target audience, Präsens may be easier to understand, matches the way they would retell a story much more closely, and, moreover, evades disruptions by the child asking at every second sentence: "Warum sagst du immer 'war' und nicht 'ist'?" ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Kids are used to stories being set in the past, I don't think this would be a problem. My impression from a fast read is that this is supposed to a (quite platitudinous) fable about current events or problems, and my guess would be that that's the reason why it is set in present tense.

Comment: @HalvarF: "Kids are used to stories being set in the past, I don't think this would be a problem." - I have just taken the topmost 20 books from my little children (skipping the ones that are not "stories") out of the bookshelf in the next room to check. 5 of them are written in Präteritum, the other 15 are written in Präsens - mind you, not only for *very* little children, but including books meant for pre-schoolers' reading practice. And I can asssure you, these disruptive questions really do occur when reading the Präteritum ones.

Answer (score 2):

You have learnt that when writing a story the past tense of choice is the simple past and not present perfect. This is correct, but it does not mean that one cannot tell a story in the present tense. This is a stylistic choice just as in English.

Answer (score 0):

The grammatical tense systems of English and German are very different.
English has **16** tenses ([source_1](https://examplanning.com/16-tenses-in-english-grammar-formula-and-examples/), [source_2](https://englishstudyhere.com/grammar/16-tenses-in-english/), [source_3](https://englishgrammarsoft.com/16-tenses-in-english-grammar/)), but German has only **6** ([germ._source_1](https://studyflix.de/deutsch/zeitformen-deutsch-3535), [germ._source_2](https://www.nachhilfe-team.net/lernen-leicht-gemacht/zeitformen/), [engl._source](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/tenses)). And none of the German tenses matches exactly with any of the English tenses. (Even worse: The usages and even the German names of the German tenses vary between northern and southern regions within the German language. For details see below.) So, it makes absolutely no sense to use names of English tenses when you want to talk about German tenses.

In what follows, I will talk about the 4 German tenses of the present and the past. The two other tenses are the future tenses *Futur I* and *Futur II* which are out of the scope of your question. (Please consult grammar books if you want to learn more about them.)

I always give a link to the German wikipedia-article and the "official" name of the tense first, which is always a Latin loanword, and then in brackets the German name(s) and then, in another pair of brackets, a short sentence in this tense. (*»I eat«* in various tenses.)

- [Präsens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4sens) (Gegenwart) (*»Ich esse.«*)
  Used for

  - Singular events that happen in the present: *»Ich trinke gerade eine Tasse Kaffee«.*
  - Constantly recurring events that happen in the past, the present and the future: *»Ich trinke jeden Morgen Kaffee.«*
  - States, that began in the past and still continue: *»Ich arbeite seit 1982 bei Mayer & Co.«*
  - States, that are not bound to any time: *»Kugeln sind rund.«*
  - Historic events from the past: *»Als vor 65 Millionen Jahren ein Asteroid die Erde trifft, leitet dieses Ereignis das Aussterben der Saurier ein.«*
    *Präsens* is just an option for historic events. More often you'll find *Präteritum.*
  - Events that will certainly happen in the future: *»Ich gehe morgen mit Brigitte ins Kino.«*
    Usually you add a temporal adverb (*bald, morgen, demnächst, ...*) or a date or time to the sentence to make sure you're talking about the future. The tense *Futur I* is also an option (*»Ich werde morgen mit Brigitte ins Kino gehen.«*) but German native speakers prefer *Präsens.*
  - For tales: *»Es ist acht Uhr Morgens. Georg betritt das Büro. Er traut seinen Augen nicht, als der das Chaos auf seinem Schreibtisch sieht.«*
    You can use this style if you want to involve the reader more directly into the story. By using *Präsens* for tales you abolish the distinction between the stories present and the readers present. (For details see below: *Präteritum - Literary texts*)
  - During sections written in *Präteritum* or *Perfekt* to increase suspense: *»Susanne schlief ruhig und fest, als sie plötzlich von einem Knall geweckt* <del>wurde</del> wird. *Es klang wie der Schuss einer Pistole.«*
- [Präteritum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4teritum) (In Germany: unvollendete Vergangenheit, Nachvergangenheit, Imperfekt oder 1. Vergangenheit. In Austria: Mitvergangenheit) (*»Ich aß«.*)
  The different German names that are in use in Austria and Germany already indicate the regional difference I mentioned in my introduction.
  To describe its usage, you must differentiate between three scenarios:

  - Literary texts (especially in novels)
    Präteritum is the first (and normally also the best) choice when an author decides in which tense they shall write the novel. Within the novel *Präteritum* expresses what happens to the characters while the story evolves. So, it is kind of a present-tense inside the context of the story, but the reader experiences the story after it happened, so for the reader it is a past-tense. If the novel is written in *Präteritum* it can't contain sections written in *Perfekt.* If the author wants to express, that an event happened before the main time-line of the story itself, they will use *Plusquamperfekt* (see below).
    Alternatively an author might decide not to distinguish between the story's *now* and the reader's *now.* Then they use *Präsens* as narrative tense. This trick let the reader feel as if the story did not happen in a distant past, but right now, in the readers *now.* In this case the author still can use *Präteritum* or *Perfekt* to describe events that happened before the story's *now* as described below.
  - Non-literary texts (anything that is not like a novel, but still is written, i.e. not spoken)
    You use *Präteritum* to tell about events that happened in the past and don't have a direct influence on the present. If the event reaches into the present or has a notable direct impact on the present, you need to use *Perfect* (see below).
  - Spoken language
    This is the point where regional differences come in:

    - In middle and northern parts of Germany (roughly: all German states, except Bavaria and Baden-Württemberg)
      In these regions people use *Präteritum* and *Perfekt* in spoken language the same way as it is described for non-literary written texts, although it is experienced within the last 50 or 70 years, that also in these regions the southern style influences spoken German more and more.
    - In Switzerland
      Swiss dialects (Schweizerdeutsch) have completely lost *Präteritum.* It simply doesn't exist in Swiss dialects. And therefore Swiss people also use *Präteritum* extremely rarely when they talk in Standard German (which Swiss people only do when they talk to foreigners who won't understand their dialect.) They replace it by *Perfekt.*
    - In Austria, and southern regions of Germany (roughly: Bavaria and Baden-Württemberg)
      The dialects spoken there also lost *Präteritum* during 16th century, and it was replaced by *Perfekt.* So, people in these southern regions use *Perfect* also when they talk about events from the past that don't influence the present. (In Hamburg: »Am 15. März 1967 regnete es.« In Vienna: »Am 15. März 1967 hat es geregnet.«)
      But some verbs are an exception (*sein* and modal verbs). They are also in southern regions used the way described for non-literary texts. (Not *»Ich bin krank gewesen«* but *»Ich war krank«.*)
- [Perfekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfekt_im_Deutschen) (In Germany: vollendete Gegenwart, Vorgegenwart oder 2. Vergangenheit. In Austria: Vergangenheit) (*»Ich habe gegessen.«*)
  You already can read from the German names, that this tense is perceived differently in Germany and Austria:

  - spoken language

    - In Germany this tense is strongly connected to the present. It is thought as a pre-present tense. This tense is only used to describe events, that are the immediate and direct cause of the current state. (People in Bavaria and Baden-Württemberg usually use this tense like people in Austria.)
    - But in Austria, there is no connection to the present. Any event that happened in the past will be described in this tense. This is at least the situation for spoken language. Austrian people use this tense in a different way when they write.
    - For the situation in Switzerland see above (in the section about *Präteritum*)
  - In written texts the tense *Perfekt* is used as described above for spoken language in Germany, i.e. only to describe events that immediate and direct influence the present. Since the stories told in novels never have an immediate and direct impact to the readers present life, they are never written in *Perfekt.* Very rare exceptions are novels written from Austrian authors that are written only for the Austrian market. (Like the novels from Wolf Haas. On Literaturhaus.at you can read a [reading sample](http://www.literaturhaus.at/index.php?id=7338) from one of his novels.)
- [Plusquamperfekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plusquamperfekt) (vollendete Vergangenheit, Vorvergangenheit oder 3. Vergangenheit) (*»Ich hatte gegessen.«*)
  This is the least frequently used German past tense.

  - In written texts it is used to describe events that happened in the past, before another event that also happened in the past.
  - In novels this is the tense usually used to describe events that happened before the time-line of the story. (*»Erika war besorgt um Martin, <del>denn er erhielt am Vortag einen seltsamen Anruf</del> denn  er* hatte *am Vortag einen seltsamen Anruf* erhalten.«)
  - In spoken language you can find *Plusquamperfekt* as standard narration tense for events that happened in the past in some dialects (Ripuarian dialects, but also Berlin dialect), while in most other dialects it doesn't exist at all and therefore also is used very rarely when people speak Standard German. In some dialects of southern regions *Plusquamperfekt* is often replaced by another tense, that doesn't exist in Standard German: [Doppeltes Perfekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppeltes_Perfekt). Example in Bavarian dialect: *»I hob gessn khobt.«* (Standard German vocabulary, but Bavarian grammar: *»Ich habe gegessen gehabt.«*)

Comment: The comparison that English has 16 tenses and German has only 6 is unfair. Just because continuous forms are not used in German does not mean they do not exist. The sentence _I werde wartend sein._ is grammatical (Zukunfts-Verlaufsform), even it is absolutely uncommon, unlike its English counterpart _I will be waiting._

Comment: @rexkogitans: Quote: *"it is absolutely uncommon"* - that's the point. It is so uncommon, that nobody mentiones it in any grammar textbook about Standard German, similar to [Doppeltes Perfekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppeltes_Perfekt) (*»Ich habe gegessen gehabt«*), [am-Progressiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am-Progressiv) (*»Ich bin am Essen«*) (aka »Rheinische Verlaufsform«) and *tun + Infinitiv* (*»Ich tu(e) essen«*). These all (plus some even more exotic forms) are tenses used in small geographic regions, maybe even only among some small social ...

Comment: ... groups and always only in colloquial speech. They do not belong to Standard German. No serious newpaper will print sentences in such a tense and no professional newscaster would use such a tense. They are considered to be wrong in all three variations of Standard German. Although some other tenses exist in German dialects or in colloquial speech, Standard German still has only 6 grammatical tenses.

Comment: Präsens and Präteritum can even both be used in the same story. The story *Ein Landarzt* by Franz Kafka starts with Präteritum, then the tense changes to Präsens.

Comment: You should try to write shorter answers. I didn't read it because it's too long.

Comment: @Alina: I try to give comprehensive answers. Very often they are highly rated, but maybe you are right and sometimes I obviously give too comprehensive answers. It is sometimes difficult to find the right balance.